# Broker may not be available while running kafka on ec2 springboot

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When  iam runing docker compose file on aws ec2, below error is displaying
"Connection to node -1 (/3.45.74.77:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.imageone_container | 2024-03-19T09:15:19.776Z  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-stringgroup-2, groupId=stringgroup] Bootstrap broker 3.45.74.77:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

```
server.port=9000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/samdb
spring.datasource.username=sam
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

# Kafka Producer Configuration
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=3.45.74.77:9093
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=3.45.74.77:9093
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

# Kafka Consumer Configuration
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=3.45.74.77:9093
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.kaif.dockersringboot.entities
```

docker compose yaml file

````
version: "3"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://3.45.74.77:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  spring-boot-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: imageone
    container_name: imageone_container
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 3.45.74.77:9093
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/samdb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: sam
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 1234

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: samdb
      POSTGRES_USER: sam
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
    ```
````

Comment: Seems like you're just trying to use Docker compose, so how is EC2 related? You should use `kafka:9092` as the address, just like you did for Postgres

Comment: i am running "docker compose up" command to deploy using docker  on aws ec2

Comment: I understand that, but EC2 isn't the problem. You don't need to use its ip address anywhere in the config. Use kafka:9093